# Is it necessary to undef macros within function?

Tags: c, macros

I've seen many times code like this:

```
void func(){
  #define a ...
  ...
  #undef a
}
```

Is the `#undef` necessary at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not necessary, but the scope of a `#define` is global after the line it was defined. It will not obey the function scope, if you are thinking it will.

Comment: Did you read the warnings? `prog.cpp:14:1: warning: "somevariable" redefined`

Comment: If I have `#define a printf("test")` in `func`,I can never call `a;` in any other function. So it's not global.

Comment: @lexer see here: http://ideone.com/ULYYp Note that I don't even call `bar()`, also note that I could use a variable named `a` before the `#define`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not *necessary*.  If the macro is meant to be used only inside the function, it's probably a good idea to `#undef` it.  If you don't, that just means that the macro remains visible through the rest of the translation unit (source file).

Most macros are probably intended to be visible throughout a source file anyway, so usually the question doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. It is only necessary if you want to ensure that `a` will not be potentially available at later points in your program depending on your logic. The `define` is now global (in the current translation unit)!

From [gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html):

> If a macro ceases to be useful, it may be undefined with the `#undef'
>   directive.

Additionally,

> Once a macro has been undefined, that identifier may be redefined as a
>   macro by a subsequent `#define' directive. The new definition need not
>   have any resemblance to the old definition.

and

> However, if an identifier which is currently a macro is redefined,
>   then the new definition must be effectively the same as the old one.
>   Two macro definitions are effectively the same if:
>
> - Both are the same type of macro (object- or function-like).
> - All the tokens of the replacement list are the same.
> - If there are any parameters, they are the same.
> - Whitespace appears in the same places in both. It need not be
>     exactly the same amount 
>      of whitespace, though. Remember that comments count as
>     whitespace.

Comment: But it is never available anywhere else besides in itself.

Comment: @lexer: What programs? I never said *other* programs.

Comment: But through my test, it seems macros defined in function can never be used outside, so it seems unnecessary to me. I'm using `gcc` to compile.

Comment: @lexer: You are right. But consider this: Maybe you are someone with a large function and many #defines. Maybe your logic relies on this. It *may* be beneficial to perform an undef.

Comment: So it just make the code neat,but with identical functionality?

Comment: @lexer: What do you mean? The #define is global. #undef is the right way unless you know it won't interfere.

Comment: @lexer: How so? As you can see from the error message, `somevariable` exists outside of `main`

Answer (score 1):

When i declare a macro like you did inside the body of a function then i would #undef it at the end. Because most probably it is meant for that function body only.

In general it is always a good idea to `#undef` a macro when you know that the macro definition is not going to be used anytime later because the macro definition propagate to all other files which include the file having a macro.